# Errors are displayed next to the input but not in the div container

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(element, value, param){
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testform").validate({
        onkeyup: function(element){$(element).valid()},
        onfocusout: false,
        errorContainer: "#errors",
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: true,
                notEqualTo: "select"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Zadejte své jméno",
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 3 znaky"
            },
            surname: {
                required: "Zadejte své příjmení",
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 2 znaky"
            },
            gender: {
                notEqualTo: "Zvolte pohlaví"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

ErrorContainer doesn't work. All errors are displayed next to the input but not in the div container. But I have `<div id="errors"></div>` in my form. Console of the web browser displays no syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Uses an additional container for error messages. The elements given as the errorContainer are all shown and hidden when errors occur. However, the error labels themselves are added to the element(s) given as errorLabelContainer, here an unordered list.

This means that if you supply `errorContainer` you also need to supply `errorLabelContainer`. Alternatively you can just use `errorLabelContainer` by itself. Try this:

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(element, value, param){
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testform").validate({
        onkeyup: function(element){$(element).valid()},
        onfocusout: false,
        errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: true,
                notEqualTo: "select"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Zadejte své jméno",
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 3 znaky"
            },
            surname: {
                required: "Zadejte své příjmení",
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 2 znaky"
            },
            gender: {
                notEqualTo: "Zvolte pohlaví"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div id="errors"></div>

<form id="testform">
    <input name="firstname" />
    <input name="surname" />
    <input name="gender" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're missing the `errorContainer` property itself

Comment: > `Alternatively you can just use errorLabelContainer by itself.`